# C++ - std::vector safe multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, shared-memory

I'm developing a program to calculate the determinant of matrix (probably big, up to 1000 rows). 
Since it can be big, I use multi-threading when the `dim(M) > 250` ( < 250 calculates in 100 ms).

My idea is to split the matrix in 4 parts and Gauss eliminate each part simultaneously, then recollect the matrix and calculate the determinant.

I would like to know, if it is safe to access one vector in multiple threads, since it's guaranteed that I will only access the different parts of it?

Also, what tips are good to limit the memory usage? 
I use `vector<vector<double>>`, so  `8 * 1000 * 1000 doubles` can be a really big trouble.

Comment: A single vector would use less memory (and be faster) then a vector of vectors.

Comment: Very large matrices like this are often sparse. If that's your case, you may want to use use an encoding like CSR instead of a dense representation.

Comment: If doing this with threads is the point of the exercise, fine, but if you only want the answer, it's hard for me to think that you'll do better with multithreading that just using some pre-existing numerical computation library, like LAPACK or similar.

Comment: @Galik, well, but is it more likely to use though? The memory profit is 24*n (pointer per each internal vector) which is max. 3MB, but traversing becomes much less obvious. How would you measure speed difference?
BTW, is it true that O(n) cycle, where n = 10^9 is faster than O(n^2) where n = 1000?

Comment: thanks for advices. yeah, the point of the exercise is not to use external libraries, but to use multi-threading

Comment: @LevKolomazov With a single *vector* the memory is all contiguous so it should be more cache friendly with the CPU. A *vector of vectors*, on the other hand, has each vector allocate a different contiguous block for each row. That's why I assume there should be a performance benefit. Also, with *vector of vectors* you have a **double dereference** with every read/write.

Comment: @Galik, okay. Obviously single vector is faster, as you said. But I assume the performance improvement is not more than 5%. I still would prefer the matrix for now though. Maybe later I'd have to switch. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe as far as you don't change its size.

The content of the vector won't be moved unless you make a resize. So as long as you access to different parts of the memory it is safe.

Comment: Even accessing the same part would be safe so long as it were only reading.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir making a Gauss elimination isn't a read-only action.